# How can I determine what various /dev/disk* map to on Mac OS X / macOS?

Tags: mac, iso-image

On macOS, I'm trying to learn how to determine what a given 'disk' (as listed under /dev/disk*) maps to.
E.g., in the following, I can't tell from "ls" or "df" that /dev/disk5 is associated with the .iso disk file ... but the Mac "Disk Utility" can!

Example:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk*
brw-r-----  1 root    operator    1,   0 Apr 30 13:06 /dev/disk0
brw-r-----  1 root    operator    1,   3 Apr 30 13:06 /dev/disk0s2
brw-r-----  1 root    operator    1,  10 Apr 30 13:06 /dev/disk3
brw-r-----  1 root    operator    1,  12 Apr 30 13:06 /dev/disk3s2
br--r-----  1 sieler  staff       1,  13 May  4 15:06 /dev/disk5

$ df
Filesystem            512-blocks       Used  Available Capacity   iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2          1873705792 1586327624  286866168    85% 198354951  35858271   85%   /
/dev/disk3s2          5859794856 2811923000 3047871856    48% 351490373 380983982   48%   /Volumes/sea3b
/dev/disk5               8282556    8282556          0   100% 18446744073707482787   2070639 1019157131144059776%   /Volumes/CSLA_X64FREO_EN-US_DV5
```

From Disk Utilility I see:

- disk0 is an internal SATA drive.
- disk3 is an external USB drive.
- disk5 is a .iso file that has been mounted as a drive.

I'd like to be able to determine the same thing (SATA, USB, .iso) with non-GUI commands
(or, better yet, via functions callable from C, but I'll screen-scrape command line tool output if I have to :)

Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mount` to determine which mounted volumes corresponds to which `/dev/diskX` devices. Alternatively you can Use `⌘I` in Disk Utility to see what `/dev/diskX` identifier a particular volume uses.

Comment: thanks, this (using 'mount') answered it for me!  (The Disk Utility method is interesting, but not amenable to screen-scraping / capturing the result programmatically.)